# AWS network connection failed: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services

I setup an Ubuntu EC2 instance and that was working fine and I allocated an elastic IP to my instance. But recently I am trying to connect to my instance using SSH putty and WinSCP from my windows but it throws **connection timed out** error. I have already checked the following things

1. SSH port 22 enabled in Security groups
   [image]
2. My other AWS account is running via putty so there is no firewall issue in my system.
3. After allocating to elastic IP, I have changed the IP in Putty.
4. Restarted the EC2 instance
5. Connect the security group to my EC2 instance.

Please help me. It worked a couple of times already and I successfully logged into the instance but now getting the connection timed out error.

Comment: Did you check (or edit) your security groups?

Comment: Yes you can see the security groups configuration. I have also assigned/connect this group to my instance

Comment: Ok, I meant that you have HTTP Inbound not specified (0.0.0.0). It's valid only for Outbound. You cannot connect directly to the instance from everywhere but only by Elastic IP. In your case first row has to be set to specific IP range

Comment: What have you selected in the source for SSH inbound? Have you selected "My IP" or you added your ip address?? Is it possible that you machine IP address changed?

Comment: @AlexGera currently HTTP inbound is not hurting me. Its SSH because I cannot connect via SSH. So currently I am trying to login via SSH and have opened everything for now just to get logged in but getting **connection timed out** error

Comment: SSH listening port 22 over TCP. And it has to be running as ssh deamon on the instance. There is a massive troubleshooting article in docs:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html .

Answer (score 0):

Your security group looks fine . Hope You have assigned your own VPC & Subnet for your instance.Even if its default or user defined , Please check below points and try again.

1. In routing table select mapped routing table : In routes check whether associated VPC has routes to Internet gateway.(Destination should be 0.0.0./0 and Target should be your IGW).
2. Check Subnet Associations :whether your subnet associated or not . If not, do associate and do ssh now ..

I have created mentioned issue in my Account and I have followed above steps to fix the issue . Its worked for my self .